# PyCharm Shortcut and Actions statistics

Tags: pycharm

I know my favourite shortcuts and actions, but I trust statistics more than my brain.

Is there a way to get counts how often I use a pyCharm shortcut or action?

Answer (score 1):

Try Help > Productivity guide for some action statistics

To keep a record of your shortcut usage you can probably add your shortcuts as custom keystrokes to a keystroke counter like Skywire Empire's **KeyCounter** http://skwire.dcmembers.com/wb/pages/software/keycounter.php

Comment: I forgot to mention: I run ubuntu linux. I guess this software needs ms-windows.

Comment: It claims to have a portable zip file check this https://whatpulse.org/ as well, it may suite your needs